# Do I need to initialize std::string

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, stdstring

I have this code:

```
class myclass
{
    std::string str;
public:
    void setStr(std::string value)
    { 
        str=value;
    }
    std::string getStr()
    {
        return str;
    }
 }

 main()
 {
   myclass ms;
   std::cout<<ms.getStr()<<std::endl;
 }
```

when I compile and run this code, there is  o error and in windows I am always getting str as "".

Is this always valid?

I need the above behavior in the fact that if user did not call set, str would be always a blank string.

should I initialize str in constructor as follow:

```
class myclass
{
    std::string str;
public:
    myclass():str(""){}
    void setStr(std::string value)
    { 
        str=value;
    }
    std::string getStr()
    {
        return str;
    }
 }
```

I want to make sure that behavior is the same on all platform and also  make sure that code is as small and neat as possible.

Comment: *Do I need to initialize std::string* --> No.

Comment: @liliscent Is the behavior guarantee? is the constructor of string called? when they are called?

Comment: @drescherjm Thanks, it is fixed now.

Answer (score 8):

> Do I need to initialize std::string

No. `std::string` default constructor initialises a nice empty string for you.

> I want to make sure that behavior is the same on all platform and also make sure that code is as small and neat as possible.

Remove clutter then:

```
struct myclass {
    std::string str;
};
```

[Fundamental types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) though, do not get initialised by default, you need to initialize them explicitly:

```
struct myclass {
    std::string str;
    int i = 1; // <--- initialize to 1.
};
```

Comment: What if I have an int in the class too? Is it initialized to zero?

Comment: @mans it is a good habit to check the doc (RTFM) about a specific constructor. Here, go and read [`std::string::string()` (string's default constructor)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string).

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to initialize a `string` member with an empty string, though it can help to do it anyhows. Consider:

```
struct foo {
    std::string a;
    std::string b;
    foo() : a("foo") {}
};
```

Was it by accident or on purpose that `b` does not get a value in the constructor? I'd prefer

```
foo() : a("foo"), b() {}
```

because it makes the intend explicit for no price (not counting a few keystrokes).

Comment: How about `foo() : a("foo"), b() {}`?

Comment: @NathanOliver even better